# How to dynamically delete MongoDB entry using API route

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would just like to simply delete a record from a dynamically displayed list. I've tried every permutation of the backend code and ai just can't get it to work.

The backend is called like this:

```
async function deletePost() {
    setLoading(true)
    try {
        await axios.delete(`/api/delete/${id}`)
        alert("Post deleted")
    }
    catch (err) {
        // notify user that something went wrong
        console.log(err)
    }
    finally {
        setLoading(false)
    }

    setLoading(false)
}
```

And /api/delete/${id} looks like this:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "util/mongodb"
export default async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.query;
    console.log(id)
    try {
        const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
        await db.collection("users").deleteOne({'_id': `ObjectId("${id}")`})
        res.sendStatus(200).send({ done: true })
    }
    catch (error) {
        return res.json({ error })
    }
 }
```

The console log shows the correct post id, the alert in the 'try' frontend code displays, but the dam post just wont delete. Can anyone offer any advice please?  I have tried ".deleteOne({'_id': id})" but that does nothing either.

Comment: Which client are you using? `mongoose` or `mongodb`?  I am almost sure the problem is on this piece of code: ``ObjectId("${id}")``. ObjectId should be a method/class you import from one of the previous mentioned libraries and pass in the `id` variable. It should't be a string.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. I didn't realise I had to import the ObjectId method/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are searching for a string, instead of the ObjectId, so no documents match.

You can fix it by converting to ObjectId and then using the value converted, `.deleteOne`.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; 
const { id } = req.query;     
const convertedObjectId = new ObjectId(id);
db.collection("users").deleteOne({_id: convertedObjectId })
```

Actual example from documentation:

```js
try {
   db.orders.deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId("563237a41a4d68582c2509da") } );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

Reference: [MongoDB Documentation - Delete One](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#delete-a-single-document).

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed problem:**

```js
app.delete("/cars/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const carsId = req.params.id;
    const query = { _id: ObjectId(carsId) };
    const result = await carCollection.deleteOne(query);
    res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.